# How can i write a unit test for a trigger in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

I have a trigger that i have written that I need tested to be able to get code coverage in salesforce:

here is the trigger:

```
Trigger MyCh_SALESFORCETRIGGERUPDATE_tr_I on Account (after insert) 
{
    set<ID> ids = Trigger.newMap.keyset(); 
    for(ID id : ids) 
    {
    MyCh_Account__c change = new MyCh_Account__c();
    change.Action__c = 'insert'; 
    change.Link__c = id; 
    change.Processed__c = false; 
    change.Map__c = 'SALESFORCE TRIGGER UPDATE'; 
    insert change;
    }
}
```

I have tried :

```
@isTest
public class MyAccountcreationTest
{
    static testMethod void testMethod1()
    {
        Account testAccount = new Account();
        testAccount.Name='Test Account' ;
        insert testAccount;

       Account acc1 = [Select Id, Link__c, Action__c, Processed__c, Map__c from Account where Id =: testAccount.Id];
       System.assertEquals(acc1.Name,'Test Account');
       System.assertEquals(acc1.Link__c, acc1.Id);
       System.assertEquals(acc1.Processed__c,false);
       System.assertEquals(acc1.Map__c,'SALESFORCE TRIGGER UPDATE');
       System.assertEquals(acc1.Action__c,'insert');
    }
}
```

I expect the test to pass but it gives an error :
Map__c , Action__c , Link__c are not fields of Account object.

Also , how does the test actually link to the trigger itself ?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `MyCh_Account__c` record in your trigger but you're not testing that in your test. You need to query for the record created in your trigger and assert that the fields are correct.

Comment: Also this nitpicky but `MyCh_Account__c` is a terrible api name. You should try to use complete words for objects and fields. It makes code more readable

Comment: I have made my fields correct , now but can i do  a select and filter via transaction ?  
for example: I insert an account , thats 1 transaction , i then update thats another. 
So i assume ther will be 2 id's for that account name. Can i filter the id's on that account name for insert like the following: 
     
List<Account> accountList = [SELECT Id, IsDeleted FROM Account WHERE Name like 'TestAccount12345%' and INSERT]  ;

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following correctly. But If you insert the account and then update the same account there will only be 1 record. But yes anything that is created while your test runs you can query in your test. By the way, when a test is running that is 1 transaction. Inserting multiple records in a test does not create a new transaction. This might be helpful https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing

Comment: that has help thanks.     but I need to format a string but cant see where there  it is in documentation.       I have                                                          
recd.selectQry = 'select Account.Id  from Account where Account.Id IN ('87654321')';

selectQry is a textArea. How can i format this as it  doesnt select the required record ?

Comment: Yikes you definitely should not be storing queries in fields on a record.